# Usage of "Not Exists" SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named **DataTable** which contains 5 columns: ****PK**,** **Name, Type, Value, ParentID**.

[image]

Now I need to merge the records whose **ParentID** = 1 into those whose **ParentID** = 2. **So the records with ParentID = 1 are to be dissolved while ParentID = 2 means to be retained.**

The merging rule is that if retained records have same **Name** and **Type** as dissolved, then just delete dissolved. otherwise update **ParentID** from 1 to 2

i.e. What I want achieve is something like

```
update DataTable set ParentID = 2 where ParentID = 1 and
(select Name, Type from DataTable where ParentID = 1)
Not Exists
(select Name, Type from DataTable where ParentID = 2)
```

The result after merge should be

[image]

Please help with the SQL Statement. Thanks.

Comment: `UPDATE` doesn't delete records, so you would seem to want `MERGE`.  You should also provide same data as text tables, DDL, or even as a db fiddle of some sort.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff. Sorry I missed the case for `DELETE`. But I also need to use `UPDATE` for the rows with a particular name and type that exists for `ParentID= 1` but not for `ParentID = 2`. So yes I want to merge (set their `ParentID` from 1 to 2). Could you please update your answer for the `UPDATE` case?

Comment: Please don't use images for data. Use formatted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . you seem to want to *delete* rows from the table where the parentid = 1 and a corresponding parentid = 2 exists.  You are not 100% clear on what "corresponding" is, but something like this:

```
delete from t
    where t.parentid = 1 and
          exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.parent_id = 2 and
                        t2.name = t1.name and
                        t2.type = t1.type
                 );
```

I see.  This fixes getting rid of the rows.  You can then do an `update`:

```
update t
    set parentid = 2
    where parentid = 1;
```

I should caution that this is subject to race conditions, if multiple threads are changing the table at the same time.  I do think that `merge` also suffers from race conditions, so using `merge` wouldn't fix that problem.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter (a pet peeve of mine is downvotes without a comment on the reason) but it might be because the delete alone will not change the `ParentID` value to 2 for PK 1 per the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comment by @GordonLinoff, this can also be accomplished with a `MERGE` statement.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.t;
CREATE TABLE dbo.t(
     PK int PRIMARY KEY
    ,Name varchar(10)
    ,Type varchar(10)
    ,Value varchar(10)
    ,ParentID int
    ,UNIQUE(Name, Type, PK)
);
INSERT INTO dbo.t VALUES
     (1,'str','string','abc',1)
    ,(2,'b','bool','Y',1)
    ,(3,'b','bool','N',2)
    ,(4,'str','enum','abc',2);
GO
MERGE dbo.t AS target
USING (
    SELECT
         Name
        ,Type
        ,Value
    FROM t
    WHERE t.parentid = 2) AS source ON
        source.Name = target.Name
        AND source.Type = target.Type
        AND target.ParentID = 1
WHEN MATCHED THEN DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND target.ParentID <> 2 THEN UPDATE SET ParentID = 2;
```

Comment: `UNIQUE(Name, Type, PK)` You know that does nothing useful. Did you accidentally include PK?

Comment: @SMor, I included a unique constraint on the composite natural key intentionally to suggest it's needed for data integrity. It seems `PK` is a surrogate `IDENTITY` primary key based on the column name and sample data, which won't prevent dups by itself. These constraints are beyond the scope of the question but a best practice, IMHO.